# Adding MP3 Tags using Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x

Request your help as I am attempting to use an excel document to add MP3 Tags.  When it is ran it adds the last entry of the excel document to all of the MP3 files. What I  am attempting to do is to add each individual entry to each MP3 file. How can solve this?  Thanks.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
    import os
    import eyed3
    import datetime
    
    os.chdir('C:\\users\\info\\Desktop\\')
    book = load_workbook('Test.xlsx')
    sheet = book['Sheet1']
    
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Info\\Desktop\\The Holy Spirit Insie Me Vol 1\\The Holy Spirit Insie Me Vol 1 - Copy\\')
    for filename in os.listdir():
        #if filename.endswith('.mp3'):
            #os.unlink(filename)
           for row in sheet.rows:
                 #Current_Date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime ('%y-%m-%d')
                 audiofile = eyed3.load('C:\\Users\\info\\Desktop\\The Holy Spirit Insie Me Vol 1\\The Holy Spirit Insie Me Vol 1 - Copy\\'+ filename)
                 audiofile.tag.artist = (row[3].value)
                 audiofile.tag.album = (row[2].value)
                 audiofile.tag.album_artist = (row[3].value)
                 audiofile.tag.title = (row[2].value)
                 audiofile.tag.track_num = (row[0].value)
                 audiofile.tag.save()
    
    
    print(filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd for loop iterates through all the rows of the sheet and assigns each in turn till you end up with last row.  You want to either use a specific row (by searching for the file in your sheet to identify the right row; it's okay to use the 2nd for loop for that, you just need figure to only set the values conditionally if it's the right row), or define a row number that you increment in the outer loop that you then use to index into sheet.rows (this assumes os.listdir() return files in a well-defined order.  If it doesn't sort the result first).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have been looking but not coming up with much detail.  Can you recommend some websites/information for me to checkout?  Thanks

Comment: I would look for a program that was design for this rather than rolling your own.  Not sure what OS you use but on Linux there are id3, id3ren, id3tool, id3v2, libid3-tools, mp3info, mp3info-gtk etc.  My library is stored in artist/album/track - title.format, and one of those, I believe it was id3ren, can update the file based on the path.  This made it really convenient to fix things.  The two suggestions above would should work for you.  Another way that might help you is to write function that takes a file name, and the information you want to set.  Then you can easily see what to pass in.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I  am working in Windows and thanks for the suggestions provided.  All this is still so new so I am picking up as I go.  If anything I will reach out.  Thanks

Comment: @GiddyHeaD if the answer was helpful please make it as such, and either indicate that the question was answered or close it.

Comment: It is helpful information it gave me some insight.  Due to a program App glitch a reset of computer was neccessary. Will work on it shortly.  Once again thanks for the direction and insight.